# Can batch programming use to read variables that inside .java and make change of it?

Tags: java, batch-file

Can I use batch programming to read java codes and identify the variables (inside .java or .class) and create a loop at batch programming and modify the variables?

For example

```
**Inside java**
String s = "abc";
```

Can batch programming read into java and retrieve the "String s" and modify using batch programming?

### Thank you for your views, comments and answers.

Let me explain why am I asking this question.
I have a java code that able to pull files from FTP. There are many folders inside the FTP. And the java code able to pull files from each folder.One year got 52 weeks means that the FTP got 52 folders. I just want to pull files up to 3 weeks back but not 52 weeks. So I suggested them to create a simple function into java codes to pull files up to 3 weeks. But they said they prefer not to touch the java codes. Because they said in future there might be other vendor use this java codes to pull files.So they think that if create a batch file to solve this problem, in future they just need to change the setting in the batch files. They said "if I make changes in java,in future if there are 10 vendors, are you going to maintain 10 java codes?" So they request me to use batch programming to do it. =/. So I am asking is it possible to use batch programming to read variables and modify the variables and return to the java codes. If still unclear, please do ask me. I am willing to answer it.

Comment: Do u want to change the .class variable?

Comment: No you cannot do this. The bigger question is: Why do you want to do this? If you tell us your real goal, we can probably give you easier alternatives.

Comment: @muthu Yup. This is what I want to ask. Can I change it using batch programming?

Comment: @Jason C Hi Jason, I am a GT at a company. I suggested them just make a function inside java and make change of the variables. But they said that they prefer not to touch the java. Because of future might use of it. They want it more dynamic. So they asked me try to make this changes using batch programming.

Comment: @user2709555. It is not possible to change .class file

Comment: @muthu Ok, I got it. Thank you Muthu

Comment: None of that really makes any sense. Without knowing exactly what your situation is, a more traditional approach would be to make the Java program itself take configuration options on the command line or through a configuration file.

Comment: @JasonC Thank you Jason. I will take note of this and let them know what situation I am in right now. Hope they will understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is can I use batch programming to read java codes and identify the variables (inside .java or .class) and create a loop at batch programming and modify the variables?

In theory, yes.

In practice, it would be tricky (i.e. you would need to do some difficult Java programming to achieve it).  And it is a BAD IDEA to modify the code like that, either at the source code or compiled code level.  There are much simpler, safer and more transparent ways to implement the setting of configuration variables.

The normal way to handle variables that need to be changed for different runs of a program is to load the variables from a configuration file, or set them based on the command's command-line arguments, system properties or environment variables.

> I will take note of this and let them know what situation I am in right now. Hope they will understand.

It is your job (as an IT professional) to *convince* them that they shouldn't ask for something really stupid ...